# How to successfully connect to kerberos authenticated mongod instance from java application?I'm getting exception initializing GSSAPI Credentials

Tags: mongodb, kerberos, mongo-java-driver

I've started mongod instance in kerberos auth mode.I'm able to connect from mongo shell.While connecting from java application,I get the following exception:

```
Key for the principal mongodb/****@**** not available in ***.keytab
        [Krb5LoginModule] authentication failed 
Unable to obtain password from user
```

My gss-jaas.conf is

```
com.sun.security.jgss.initiate {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
useKeyTab=true
useTicketCache=false
principal="mongodb/***@***"
doNotPrompt=true
keyTab="D:\***.keytab" 
debug=true;};
```

I've used ktuil and executed following commands to write principal to keytab file.Can anyone help me to find out what's going wrong?

```
ktutil:  add_entry -password -p mongodb/***@*** -k 1 -e des-cbc-md4
Password for mongodb/***@***: 
ktutil:  wkt /tmp/***.keytab 
ktutil:  quit
```

I've entered the password and also tried by skipping it with enter.In both the cases,I'm getting the above exception.I've used the following system properties in java application:

```
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf","D:\\krb5.conf");
                        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config","D:\\gss-jaas.conf");
                        System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly","false");
                          System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.realm","****");
                            System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.kdc","*****");
                        kerberosCredential = MongoCredential.createGSSAPICredential(userName);
```

Comment: Do you run the MongoDB Enterprise edition?

Comment: Locate the driver documentation regarding kerberos configuration, link it from question, then update the question with which steps worked and which steps did not.

Comment: I would bet on Java interpreting \ as an **escape character** in JAAS conf => use Unix syntax for Windows paths i.e. `D:/wtf/duh.keytab` or escape the \ i.e. `D:\\wtf\\duh.keytab`

Comment: Just raise the debugging flags to understand what happens -- most configuration errors are silently ignored by default, that's why you need these flags i.e. `-Djava.security.debug=gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser‌​,logincontext`

Comment: Thanks @SamsonScharfrichter.I've added system property -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true.Logs are >>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): mongodb
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): **hostname**@realm
>>> KeyTab: load() entry length: 101; type: 26
Looking for keys for: mongodb/**hostname**
Java config name: D:/krb5.conf
Loaded from Java config
Found unsupported keytype (26) for mongodb/**hostname**@realm
Key for the principal mongodb/**hostname**@realm not available in D:/user.keytab
  [Krb5LoginModule] authentication failed 
Unable to obtain password from user